# Having issues reading an excel file (fs readFilesync error)

Tags: reactjs, excel, typescript, fs, file-read

I am stuck on this error from quite sometime. I am trying to read an excel file (.xlsx file) using the xlsx package.
`import XLSX from 'xlsx'`

This is how I read the excel file

`var workbook = XLSX.readFile('./file.xlsx');`

This file is in the same folder as the code is in. So the path seems to be right as well.

I do not get any compile time errors, but when I go on the UI and click the download button, the above line is triggered (reading from an excel file), and this is the error that is seen:

[image: Error while trying to read the excel file]

Looks like xlsx package is trying to use fs package from @types/node module.

I have also installed @types/node package which is required for fs.
I even tried to check if file sync works and tried reading a file via fs.readFileSyn ... but I keep getting an error during compile time (when I do npm run start), that `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ...`
I tried importing fs in these two ways:
`import * as fs from 'fs'` 
`import fs from 'fs'`  I tried with require as well.

but none of those these worked.

note: My webpack file has css loader and a ts loader. I'm not too sure if  webpack(loaders) could be the issue. Let me know if this could be the issue and why?

Can someone please help me resolve the above error mentioned? I'm trying to figure this one out from quite sometime.

Comment: This module is intended for a nodejs server, not for a browser, and it seems like you are trying to use it on a browser. You can't just access the filesystem on a browser, therefor there is no fs module to import and use.

Comment: Thank you @RaniSharim I missed that one. Do you know any other module/pkg for reading an excel file in browser?

Comment: I think you could use the same package, but not read the file directly. You need to make a form with file input, make the user choose a file and then read from there. See examples in the npm page (the last two) https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: Nope, I do not want to choose it. That is the use case here.. this is a static file which is always going to be downloaded when clicked on the download button. This file shd be available when the user clicks on the download button.

Comment: Ah, in that case see the option "Browser download file".